# Flutter & Firebase- Firebase Analytics setUserProperty for Anonymous users

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-analytics, flutter-web

Cannot set user property- getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'statusCode' of null` in Flutter Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing

```dart
WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
  FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();
analytics.setUserId(userCredential.user.uid);
analytics.setUserProperty(name:"xxxx",value:"xxxxx");
```